# Looking for a string inside a list

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying different scenarios with the following code and can't seem to get the right code. I am trying to look in a list for a word and return True. The word that I am looking for is "Jack", but the list contain "Jackie" which is incorrect, but the code return True.

```
def name_finder(listName,name):
if listName.find(name)!= -1:
    return True
else:
    return False

nameList = "Joshua Diaddigo, Marguerite Murrell, Jackie Elliott"

print(name_finder(nameList,"Jack"))
print("Done!")
```

Any help would be appreciated even if it is a hint to where to start.

Comment: You need to reproduce your indentation accurately when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new problems into the code people are trying to help you with.

Comment: You are trying to check whether `"Jack"` is present in the string `nameList`. So, you will get only `True`

Comment: Sorry about the indentation and yes I am looking for "Jack'

Answer (score 1):

one way is to use the [regex module](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
def name_finder(lst, name):
    re_str = '(^|\ |,){}($|\ |,)'.format(name)
    return re.search(re_str, lst) != None
```

the regular expression matches <'the beginning of the string' or 'a space' or 'a comma'> followed by the name followed by <'the end of the string' or 'a space' or 'a comma'>. there may be more elegant ways to write a regex for that...

Comment: `lst.split()` will split only by spaces. But there is some elements with `,`. I think you have to loop again and remove the `,`.

Comment: @ChihebNexus you are right; that did not work at all! removed it... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to find a whole word in a string, you can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) with the **word boundary symbol**, `\b`.

```
import re
def name_finder(names, name):
    return (re.search(r'\b%s\b'%re.escape(name), names) is not None)
```

Comment: yep. that is more elegant than mine!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your name_list in python's list datatype, You can do that by this way,

```
nameList = "Joshua Diaddigo, Marguerite Murrell, Jackie Elliott"
nameList = nameList.split(',')
name = "Jack"

def name_finder(nameList,name):
    if name in nameList:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: apart from the fact that your code indentation is off, `def name_finder(nameList.split(','),name):` is invalid syntax in python...